# Google cloud app engine and Flask application infinitely loading

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, gcloud

I have been trying to deploy a web application that using Google cloud app engine. My Application uses Flask and sqlalchemy to connect to a mysql google cloud database. The website gets created but when trying to click on the link it just loads infinitely. The logs aren't pointing me in any direction.

Currently this is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  operating_system: ubuntu22

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

This was copied directly from the Gcloud example files. My main.py file is

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

And this is my **init**.py file which is within my Website folder

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Secret Key'

    PASSWORD = "DB Password"

  

    PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS = "Ip address of database"
    
      
    
    DBNAME = "Database Name"
    
      
    
    PROJECT_ID = "Project Id"
    
      
    
    INSTANCE_NAME = "Instance Name"
    
      
    
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"mysql+mysqldb://root:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}/{DBNAME}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{PROJECT_ID}:{INSTANCE_NAME}"
    
      
    
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

This is my first time deploying a website so this may be an easy fix but I have no clue what I can change so any tips help a lot!

Comment: Won't solve your issue, but... Your application could use App Engine standard. Else, use Cloud Run instead of App Engine Flex. You also should use Secret manager instead of secret in config file

Comment: so stupid question, but does this run locally? Also, move your imports to the top of `init.py`

Comment: @EdoAkse    Yes it runs perfectly fine locally, even when I connect it with my a google cloud mysql database.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere This would just change the format of my app.yaml file correct?

Comment: @AlexTotheroh I have since changed the Werkzeug version and now my application will load but I am left with a 500 Server Error that tells me to try again in 30 seconds. Also when I check my versions it shows that my version has 0 instances.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere

> Won't solve your issue, but... Your application could use App Engine standard. Else, use Cloud Run instead of App Engine Flex. You also should use Secret manager instead of secret in config file

guillaume blaquiere is right, switching from **App Engine Flex** to **App Engine standard** or **Cloud Run** may help you fix your problem. A managed environment called **App Engine standard** is created specifically for running web apps. It may be more performant for your application than **App Engine Flex** and is simpler to set up and configure.

**Cloud Run** is a serverless computing platform that allows you to run your code without having to manage servers. It is a good option for applications that experience sudden spikes in traffic, as it can automatically scale up and down to meet demand.

Use **Secret Manager** to keep your secrets, including database passwords, safe. Your application will become more manageable and secure as a result.

The following documentation is available if you need assistance migrating to **App Engine standard** or **Cloud Run**:

- [Deploying a Flask application to App Engine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart)
- [Deploying a Flask application to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python)
- [Using Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview)